# Linux on USB with / mounted on Pendrive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, usb-boot, linux-mint

I'm wondering how to install Linux Ubuntu/Mint on Pendrive so that / (root fs) is mounted
directly on USB in RW mode ?

I think that most installers simply copy the installation CD onto pendrive. And in fact you have installer on usb stick.

What I want is to have normally installed linux on pendrive just as I would on HD ?

Maybe I don't understand something here. PLS don't kill me :-)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know specifically about Ubuntu/Mint, but in general USB drives don't look any different to system than regular disks.

You may need to play around with the installer to force it to install to an USB drive, but it certainly won't copy contents of the CD, as they are, to USB. That would create an USB installation media, not an USB install.

Comment: Seconded. I have installed Linux and OpenBSD on USB flash drives and SD cards several times w/o any issues. Just pay attention to the device name, since you may accidentally erase the real HDD if you get that wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Just copying the installation CD won't work. Use [liveUSB-creator](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/) to turn the USB drive into a live install of the OS, and set the `Persistent Storage` to a larger size. The Persistent Storage is essentially the hard drive of the install. It is where the live OS will store all of its data, and any applications you install.

Comment: Thanks. What is the mount point of persistent storage ?

Comment: Is root (/) mounted in RW mode ?